EasyInstallDeprecationWarning: easy_install command is deprecated. With ROS2 Jazzy on Ubuntu 24.04 Noble Numbat
I know this issue is already documented and solved/bypassed with humble, but no solution to Jazzy with Ubuntu 24.04 is proposed at the moment.
Building a brand-new python packages causes the following warning:
--- stderr: my_new_python_pkg                                                                                                 
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/develop.py:40: EasyInstallDeprecationWarning: easy_install command is deprecated.
!!

        ********************************************************************************
        Please avoid running ``setup.py`` and ``easy_install``.
        Instead, use pypa/build, pypa/installer or other
        standards-based tools.

        See https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/917 for details.
        ********************************************************************************

!!
  easy_install.initialize_options(self)
---

Are there any solutions to this issue, or at least ways to suppress the warning?

This solution worked for me:
PYTHONWARNINGS="ignore:easy_install command is deprecated,ignore:setup.py install is deprecated"
export PYTHONWARNINGS

